# Why doesn't it find the element by the class?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I want to type something in the input field, but when I call it with the class it returns an error. The Website has enough time to load all Elements so that shouldn't be the problem.

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.tradingview.com/chart/')
print("a")
time.sleep(5)
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("header-toolbar-symbol-search")  # Find the search box
print("b")
elem.click()
time.sleep(5)
crypto_search = browser.find_element_by_class_name("search-Hsmn_0WX upperCase-Hsmn_0WX input-3n5_2-hI")
print("c")
crypto_search.send_keys("VETUSD")
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

When I run the code it gives me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .search-Hsmn_0WX upperCase-Hsmn_0WX input-3n5_2-hI
```

It gets to the lines where it prints the a and b but it stops at the line which calls the element with class.

Comment: Please accept an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
crypto_search = browser.find_element_by_class_name("search-Hsmn_0WX upperCase-Hsmn_0WX input-3n5_2-hI")
```

try the following:

```
crypto_search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".search-Hsmn_0WX.upperCase-Hsmn_0WX.input-3n5_2-hI")
```

I tried and it worked for me.
Also, because these class names are multiple and looking not too discriptive I would prefer the following selector:

```
crypto_search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-name='symbol-search-items-dialog'] input")
```

Comment: The first selector also looks good. I added my answer with more suggestions. `time.sleep()` is bad idea with Selenium.

Comment: @vitaliis you are absolutely right about the sleeps. I just didn't deal with this point since this is not what caused an error here

Answer (score 0):

1 Get rid of time.sleep() because your tests will become unreliable and slow. Use implicit/explicit waits

2 If you have multiple classes in one use `css` or `xpath` selectors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.tradingview.com/chart/')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "header-toolbar-symbol-search"))).click()  # Find the search box
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-Hsmn_0WX.upperCase-Hsmn_0WX.input-3n5_2-hI"))).send_keys("VETUSD")
#  browser.close()
```

Here I wait till the first element is clickable and the second is visible, as an example of how explicit waits work in Selenium.

Note, how faster my version of test is.

Answer (score -1):

according to the documentation you need to use 'find_elements'.

This is because classes are used when there will be multiple of them on a page, so it doesn't make sense to select only one element with a class name, even if there is only one on the page.

If that element is the only one with that class on the page, try using

```
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("search-Hsmn_0WX upperCase-Hsmn_0WX input-3n5_2-hI")[0]
```

Comment: "This is because classes are used when there will be multiple of them on a page" This is not true, a class can be used to uniquely identify an element. And I a confused by the suggested code you've written... if there is only one element shouldn't you use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`?

Comment: @C.Peck You are absolutely right! `search-Hsmn_0WX upperCase-Hsmn_0WX input-3n5_2-hI` is a unique locator, no more elements there containing these class names